# I can't boot into syslinux menu

Tags: installation

I tried to create a liveUSB with Unetbootin but when i boot with this usb, there was only a cursor blinking with black screen (not purple one), no option for me to install ubuntu, please help! I set the boot option to usb first priority.

My system specs is:

CPU: E3120
Main Asus P5KPL-VM
VGA: ATI HD4670
RAM: 4GB

Blinking cursor
http://i128.photobucket.com/albums/p170/longmaba/IMG_0903_zpsb7c634e1.jpg

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you trying to install?  What are your system specs?

Comment: I'd try to run it through Unetbootin again.  I've had the same problem before.

Comment: It's Ubuntu 12.04 LST Desktop i386 version. I run through Unetbootin twice, still the same. Thanks for your concern, i really want to install this OS. I edited my system specs in my first post

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu USB startup disk doesn't boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15671/ubuntu-usb-startup-disk-doesnt-boot)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not my problem here. I attached an image

Comment: Come on guy, i need some help here

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question.  That one got past the loader and had a kernel crash.

Answer (score 0):

Make Ready Live USB

1. Again download Ubuntu12.04 (32bit) from ubuntu official website.
2. Try different USB flash drive (atleast 4GB) and format in FAT32 system.
3. Download unetbootin-windows-494( or Universal-USB-Installer-1.8.1.7).
4. Run unetbootin.
5. In Unetbootin window  by default “Distribution” selected, Select Diskimage and click browsing button and select the ubuntu ISO image file(already downloaded)
6. Select the USB drive by drop down menu and press OK.
7. Continue to proceed next until finish.
8. Now Ubuntu installation Live USB is ready.

Windows partition

1. For installing Ubuntu as dual boot with windows7, In windows7 disk management shrink your C drive more than 20GB. If you can't shrink C drive using windows disk management then use EaseUs partition master in windows7 for shrinking C drive more than 20GB.The link for Easeus partition master:http://www.filehippo.com/download_easeus_partition_master_home/
2. Insert Ubuntu Live USB and restart your computer, While restarting keep pressing ESC/F2/F9/F12 depending on your bios set up and select booting with USB.
3. In the booting option select try ubuntu. If you feel Ubuntu is working well then Click Install Ubuntu in the Harddrive.
4. Select the option Installing along with Windows7, then Ubuntu will use the unallocated disk space earlier created using Easeus partition Master.

Comment: thanks, but i know how to make a liveUSB and how to get my computer boot with USB. Problem is i can't make any progress, it just freeze with black screen and blinking cursor